# Angular JS / articles is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in `services.js` in in my Angular App:

```
.factory('Articles', function($http) {

  $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4ici6').then( function(response) {
      var articles = response.data.articles;
  });

  return {
    all: function() {
      return articles;
    },
    get: function(articleId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
        if (articles[i].id === parseInt(articleId)) {
          return articles[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
})
```

It doesn't work as I get this error in the console:

```
ReferenceError: articles is not defined
    at Object.all (http://localhost:8100/js/services.js:31:14)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:4:30)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18015:14)
```

Also here is the `controller.js` code that refers to `articles`:

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, Articles) {
  $scope.articles = Articles.all();
})

.controller('NewsDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Articles) {
  $scope.article = Articles.get($stateParams.articleId);
  $scope.posttofacebook = function (){
    window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook(null, null, $scope.article.url);
  }
  $scope.posttotwitter = function (){
    window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter(null, null, $scope.article.url);
  }
})
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How *would* that work? `articles` is defined inside an async callback, you can't access it before that may even have been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$http.get` is an asynchronous call you'll have to deal with that.

Just putting it on top of your factory won't consistently work.

Try this instead:

```
.factory('Articles', function($http) {

  return {
    all: function() {
      return  $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4ici6').then(function(response) {
        return response.data.articles;
      });
    },
    get: function(articleId) {
      //Probably best here to call an API endpoint that will return a single article with the parameter's articleId
      //Something along the lines of 
      //$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4ic16/' + articleId).then(function(response) { //handle response});
    }
  };
})
```

Your controller should also be changed to handle the async function call:

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, Articles) {
  Articles.all().then(function(articles) { $scope.articles = articles });
})
```

Comment: I have no error now on the console but my page is blank. Here is the source code of the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/ephcyzbu/. Am I calling the data correctly?

Comment: I am using the exact code you posted in your answer.

Comment: It maybe a problem frome some other part. Make sure to check all controllers.

Comment: @Andrei I added the relevant controller code to handle the async call

Comment: @Andrei Not sure why you accepted the other answer, seeing he basically just copy-pasted my answer...

Comment: Because I included preventing that the call is made while the articles are already fetched, using a promise example

Comment: Sorry, modified the selected answer. Thank you very much for your help. Now I am doing the changes for the return -> get.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks, for `get` devqon has an appropriate answer if you don't control the API endpoint and have to use the `all` call

Comment: I control the API so there shouldn't be any problems using your code.

Comment: Modified the API as instructed. In the controller.js, is it correct if I call the function like this for a specific article? Articles.get($stateParams.articleId).then(function(article) { $scope.article = article }); instead of $scope.article = Articles.get($stateParams.articleId);

Comment: Shows a blank page :(

Answer (score 1):

You have your articles variable declared inside the callback of the http, so it won't be available outside of it. Move it outside:

```
.factory('Articles', function($http) {

    // declaring it here makes it available in the 'all' function
    var articles = [];

    $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4ici6').then( function(response) {
        articles = response.data.articles;
    });

    return {
        all: function() {
            return articles;
        },
        get: function(articleId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
                if (articles[i].id === parseInt(articleId)) {
                    return articles[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
})
```

But because you fetch your articles asynchronously through http, it can happen that you do the `Articles.all()` **before** the articles are fetched, resulting in an empty array. Instead, I would do it like this:

```
.factory('Articles', function($http, $q) {

    // declaring it here makes it available in the 'all' function
    var articles = [];
    var fetched = false;

    var getAll = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (!fetched) {
            $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4ici6').then( function(response) {
                articles = response.data.articles;
                fetched = true;
                deferred.resolve(articles);
            });
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(articles);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        all: getAll,
        get: function(articleId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            getAll().then(function(articles) {
                for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
                    if (articles[i].id === parseInt(articleId)) {
                        deferred.resolve(articles[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                } 

                // not found
                return deferred.reject();
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
})
```

And use it like this:

```
Articles.all().then(function(articles){
    // now the articles are available
});

Articles.get(id).then(function(article){
    // found   
}, function(){
    // not found
});
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee articles will be available when calling `all`